# Getting mail server details from an email address?

Tags: php, email, outlook, thunderbird

I've seen this done before by Mozilla Thunderbird, and most likely other email clients. What I'm looking to do is take an email address, and find the hosts method (IMAP, POP3 etc - I'm not sure what this is actually called), port, and address.

Is there any relatively easy way of doing this via an extension, or solid external API?

(P.S. I know this isn't done via regex e.g. all `*@googlemail.com`, as domains that I have with mailservers located at Google via Google Apps, still resolve to Google's details) .

Any answers, comments, advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since the email address doesn't contain any envelope data, it's not possible that Thunderbird and the like are generating what you see from solely the email address. They are parsing the email headers (which would contain all of the information you mentioned). You can do an MX lookup on the domain from the email address to get a host address, but that's about it.

Comment: @jasonbar These are the details I receive, without any password credentials (as you can see, the field is blank) http://i.imgur.com/tll2I.png. Perhaps I overstated when I spoke of ports and such? Is what I am seeing simply the host? If so, you might want to delete your comment and post it as an answer :)!

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. Notice the line "configuration found in the mozilla isp database". They're doing an MX lookup and if the mail host is known to them they populate the information for you. It's unlikely that this would automagically populate with user@some_random_domain_that_isnt_using_google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tbird isn't doing anything special - given your email address, it can make a few guesses as to what your SMTP, IMAP/POP3 server addresses are and do some probing to find out which of those guesses is right.

Pretending your address is someone@example.com, Tbird will see if `example.com` has an IP mapping and probe any server found at that IP. If no email-related ports response, then it checks for example.com's public MX servers, and probes those. It could even try some obvious defaults for servernames, like mail.example.com, pop.example.com, etc...

Only after all of its guesses are exhausted would it come back and say "you'll have to tell me yourself, I can't figure it out".

Comment: Ah I see. Well, thanks for the thorough explanation. I'll probably just add support for the largest share 95%+ of mail hosting providers, and those that use obscure (ISP for example) email address will just have to enter information manually!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full description of Autoconfiguration in  Thunderbird - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration

The first and most usefull mechanizm is using ISPDB. So to get settings for some domain is something like this: https://autoconfig.thunderbird.net/v1.1/google.com

You should replace "google.com" to your domain

Comment: I put my domain and it's not showing anything, is there anyway to get same for other domain

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to just view it with an email address, you need to view the email itself, use a client that has these features, as you said, mozilla thunderbird should have these since there a home based email system.

simply view the email through the thunderbird client and you should be able to see all the details you're after.

Comment: This has to be done in realtime however, so a check-up through Thunderbird wouldn't work. Also, you said "you need to view the email itself"? If by that you mean you actually need to log in, Thunderbird provides these details before you give any password credentials (i.e. using just the email address). Also, what did you mean by "there a home based email system"?