# How Mozilla Thunderbird uses RDF database of IMAP hosts and ports

Tags: imap, rdf, thunderbird

I'm trying to figure out how to guess of the IMAP host and port from the email. This is being done in Thunderbird and a similar question was posted here: 
[Getting mail server details from an email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669897/getting-mail-server-details-from-an-email-address)

I've looked at the thunderbird source and find RDF files with the IMAP and host and port data for Gmail and AOL. 
See: http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mailnews/base/ispdata/

My question is how is Mozilla actually using this data. It is keeping an RDF database of user supplied IMAP host and port for each domain? Or are these 2 the only domains they have data for?

I can't seem to find the code that interacts with this data. The closest I've come is with the function getIspDefaultsForUri(domainURI): 
http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mailnews/base/prefs/content/ispUtils.js#105
I'm not familiar with the mozilla thunderbird codebase so searching it is a bit painstaking right now.

On the other hand, if someone knows of a different database or web service that contains mapping of email domains to the IMAP settings that would be a great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that they use the Thunderbird's configuration data obtained from their end users and put that into their database -- that would be a pretty intrusive thing from the privacy point of view. The [TB's documentation on autoconfiguration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration) describes how they obtain the configuration data.

For the other part of your question, have a look at [RFC 6186](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6186) which uses the DNS `SRV` records for specifying the IMAP server to use (and with TB, it's [bug 342242](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=342242).